# How to set 1 months date range in Bootstrap Material date picker?

Tags: jquery

How to set 1 months date range in Bootstrap Material date picker?

https://github.com/T00rk/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your script and change the id as per your requirement

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#date-end').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({ weekStart : 0,time:false});
        $('#date-start').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({ weekStart : 0,time:false }).on('change', function(e, date)
        {
            $('#date-end').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker('setMinDate', date);
            $('#date-end').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker('setMaxDate',moment(date).add(30, 'day').format());
        });
    });
```

I disabled the time,If you want time facility as well just make `time:false` to `time:true` or simply remove it.

PS: [For your reference](http://momentjs.com/)